# Problems committing file to SVN repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit, subversive

I have a maven pom build file in the root directory of my project. When trying to synchronize with SVN repository from Eclipse (Europa), red double directed arrow is being added to the file icon. This means that both my local copy and the one in the repository have been changed since last synchronization.

When I try to do do 'Override and update...' error message is being thrown:

```
Some resources were not reverted.
Attempted to lock an already-locked dir
svn: Working copy 'C:\Java\workspaces\pro\myProject-TRUNK' locked
```

Do you have an idea what should be done in this case?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

svn cleanup ?

not sure how you'd do that from eclipse though ... but if its a standard svn working copy, you should still be able to do it with another tool.

Comment: Subclipse plugin for Eclipse now has a "cleanup" option. Right-click on the project, go to Team -> Cleanup. Worked for me today!

Answer (score 31):

In Eclipse, to do SVN clean up

Right Click on Locked Project -> Team ->Cleanup

Answer (score 8):

delete the .loc and .log files from the directory if Team->Cleanup is not available to you from subeclipse and update the resources giving you the error message earlier.

Comment: Deleting lock files worked for me today. Cleanup didn't.

Comment: for me (on Windows) the file names were `lock` and `log`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the repository has got a bit confised! You could try a 'svn cleanup' in the project directory.

You can do it on the command line, or using a different tool...

From the command prompt, you'll have to have subversion installed and on the PATH. Close Eclipse, open up a command prompt and cd to the root of the project, then type 'svn cleanup'.

You could also use [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) to do the same from Windows Explorer. Install Tortoise SVN and close Eclipse. Within Windows Explorer, navigate to the parent of your project directory, right click on the project folder and select 'Tortoise SVN' -> 'Clean up'

Comment: Subversive plugin for Eclipse just did it well. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: The problem is that if Eclipse is causing the problem that requires a cleanup, I wouldn't trust the Subclipse 'cleanup' to help me out!

Comment: 'Working Copy locked' is a working copy issue, and has nothing to do with your repository. (Other users of the same repository will not see any issues.) Just run 'svn cleanup' (or your clients command for that) to clean the workingcopy locks.

Answer (score 5):

This normally happens when you paste a directory into another in your project.

You have to create the directories manually, then paste all the files.

To solve the issue:

- Right click on the project (or on a parent directory)
- Then **team**
- Then **clean up**

Answer (score 3):

This happens if we have some pending sessions on committing our changes so we’ll need to do some clean up before we’ll have another try on committing our changes. This is how to do it.

1. Click to Team->Clean Up
2. Try again to commit..

Answer (score 3):

it's working for me.

add svn application

```
sudo apt-get install svn
cd <folder-project-name>
svn cleanup
```

Comment: Huh - after `Team -> Cleanup` failed (as well as restart and there also were no .lock files....) this did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Restart your eclipse (IDE) . Problem Solved.

Comment: I tried several of these suggestions.  This is the one that worked for me!  I'd recommend trying this one before some of the more involved solutions.

Comment: Sometimes eclipse does not sync with code. May be eclipse cache not updated.

Answer (score 2):

I went to local svn folder and removed the log file and lock files did the svn update from eclipse and everything back on track

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on project-->Team-->Refresh/Cleanup

Answer (score 1):

Right click and select Team->Refresh/Cleanup

Answer (score 1):

I see Team -> Cleanup in most answers- somehow did not work for me.

I did this -It happened twice for me.

Once I resolved Like this -- I made a backup file with my changes . I closed my eclipse -> go into the prject in windows explorer - > Go to the file in conflict -> right click -> SVN -> Revert. Now I started eclipse -> put back my changes and it worked.

Second time it happened -- That did not help. So, I had to delete the project on my eclipse workspace, and checked out the project from SVN and it worked.

-Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use TortoiseSVN -> Release lock -> Break lock